# How do you open a file and view it in a FastColoredTextBox component in c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I'm developing an HTML editor where you can edit code inside the [FastColoredTextBox.dll](https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox) component. I have an option for the SaveFile which i covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462669/how-do-i-save-a-file-in-fastcoloredtextbox).

So can anyone help with this? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to load file like to default winforms textbox. fastColoredTextBox1 is just extended textbox. I tried it and it works like charm.

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
        var loadedText = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName);
        fastColoredTextBox1.Text = loadedText;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Right you are...works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in method is `OpenFile` which, presumably, initializes the control as intended.